# Dart: How can I debounce a subset of events in a stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bloc, rxdart

In my flutter app I'm working with a single stream of `SearchEvent`, which contains multiple subclassed event types (`SearchInputChanged`, `PageRequested`, `ResultsReceived`). I'm using the Bloc library.

Is it possible to `debounce` a subset of the events? I want to debounce `SearchInputChanged` events when users are typing quickly to avoid initiating API searches that are immediately irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do what I want by splitting the initial stream, filtering and debouncing one of the splits, then merging all of them back into a single stream. I'm not sure if there are any cleaner or more performant approaches.

```dart
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/transformers.dart';

// ...

// original inbound events
Stream<SearchEvent> events = ...;

// Split into two streams, one which we will debounce
var splitEvents = StreamSplitter.splitFrom(events, 2);

var inputEvents = splitEvents[0]
    // filter to only include events that we want to debounce
    .where((event) => event is SearchInputChanged)
    .debounceTime(Duration(milliseconds: 250));

// Do reverse of filter above (note the `!` in `is!`)
var otherEvents = splitEvents[1].where((event) => event is! SearchInputChanged);

// This has debounced SearchInputChanged, plus all other events
var finalStream = StreamGroup.merge([inputEvents, otherEvents]);
```

Comment: Like your answer!

Comment: A answer without rxdart package, will be nice